# Prove disprove that for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real numbers

Tags: analysis

Can any one solve the following two for me:

1- Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be real numbers satisfying $a>b$ and $c>d$.
Does this imply that $ac>bd$? Prove or disprove.

2- From the analysis concepts find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n+n^3}{(2n)^2+2^{2n}}\,.
$$

I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite $2^{2n}$ as $4^n$. Then divide top and bottom by $4^n$. Then take the limit. You will need to know that in the long run an exponential grows far faster than any polynomial.

For the first problem, note that it says **real number**. You should be able to find an example where the result fails. Think negative!

Comment: could you be more precious, please? I mean what to divide by 4^n? what about 3^n and n^3?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=c=1$, $b=d=-2$. Clearly $a>b$ and $c>d$ but $ac < bd$.